# Парсинг страницы с помощью Jsoup. Получение предыдущего элемента

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть код страницы самиздата: http://samlib.ru/l/laaren/

Получаем его в переменную doc_author. С помощью кода

```
Element brazdel = doc_author.select("a[href^=" + bk[0].trim().replace("/", "") + "]").first();
```

получаем ссылку на книгу. Вопрос в том, как на этой же странице найти раздел, в котором эта книга содержится, с помощью того же Jsoup.

Для примера, на вышеприведенной странице есть книга "Я - ошибка. Рассвет Узумаки". Она находится в разделе "Наруто: Я - Ошибка:". Как получить этот раздел?

Answer (score 1):

У `JSoup` есть еще такие методы как `getElementsByTag` который возвращает элементы по тегам, `getElementById` и т.д.

В вашем случае необходимо получить элемент `dl`, и работая уже с ним, получить все его дочерние `p`. Разобрав их, вы получите название раздела.